# tf.divide() and tf.cast() will interrupt the gradient propagation of my program. Is there any way to solve this problem？

Tags: python, tensorflow

In python-tensorflow，`tf.divide()` and `tf.cast()` will interrupt the gradient propagation of my program. Is there any way to solve this problem? Thank you.

```
import tensorflow as tf


tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()

w0 = tf.constant([[[0, 1, 2], [1, 2, 0]], [[1, -1, 2], [0, 3, 1]]], dtype=tf.float32)
b0 = tf.constant([[[1, 2, 0], [-1, -2, 1]], [[-2, 1, 0], [0, 1, -1]]], dtype=tf.float32)
w = tf.argmax(w0, axis=-1)
b = tf.argmax(b0, axis=-1)

loss = tf.divide(w, b)
grad1 = tf.gradients(loss, w)
grad2 = tf.gradients(w, w0)
with tf.compat.v1.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(loss))
    print(sess.run(grad1))
    print(sess.run(grad2))
```

Just like this simple example, the program will be in print（ sess.run (grad1)) and print（ sess.run (grad2)) these two places prompt an error: fetch argument none has invalid type < class' nonetype '>

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please, edit the question with more details, like a minimal example of what you are trying to do, so we can understand the issue better. In any case, note that gradient can only be propagated through floating point operations, so if you are casting to or from an integer type it will not propagate through that.

Comment: Which version of Tensorflow is this? Running your code on TF 2.3.1 yields "RuntimeError: tf.gradients is not supported when eager execution is enabled. Use tf.GradientTape instead."

Comment: @AKX Thank you for your help. I used tensorflow 2.3.0. Now I have put the code before modification on it.

Comment: @blues , if what you'd like to do is find the loss of the largest value of w0 to b0, then you can use tf.math.top_k.  If that's what you'd like, please respond and I'll help you update your question and I'll post a code example

Comment: @Anton Codes My purpose is that the loss calculated through the position sequence can be backpropagated, instead of obtaining the maximum loss.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem in your example is not with [`tf.divide`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/math/divide), but with [`tf.argmax`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/math/argmax). This function returns an integer value and is not differentiable. You could cast `w` to float and then compute the gradient with respect to that casted value:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()

w0 = tf.constant([[[0,1,2],[1,2,0]],[[1,-1,2],[0,3,1]]], dtype=tf.float32)
b0 = tf.constant([[[1,2,0],[-1,-2,1]],[[-2,1,0],[0,1,-1]]], dtype=tf.float32)
w = tf.argmax(w0, axis=-1)
b = tf.argmax(b0, axis=-1)

w_f = tf.cast(w, tf.float32)
b_f = tf.cast(b, tf.float32)

loss = tf.divide(w_f, b_f)
grad1 = tf.gradients(loss, w_f)[0]
with tf.compat.v1.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(loss))
    # [[2.  0.5]
    #  [2.  1. ]]
    print(sess.run(grad1))
    # [[1.  0.5]
    #  [1.  1. ]]
```

But you will not be able to compute the gradient of `loss` with respect to `w0`, because there is a non-differentiable operation between them.